# Kali linux 2.0 failed to connect to lvmetad.Falling back to device scanning

Tags: grub, kali-linux

I added rolling repo from kali.org and did update and upgrade, then I rebooted,now I get following error on black screen

```
Warning:Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
"disk/by-uuid/7c94fada-9f32-46ca-a185-d5a1a193bfcb":Invalid path for logical volume
fsck from util-linux 2.28
/dev/sda5:clean, 343219/538080 files, 3818489/20129536 blocks
```

what's happening? Do I need to reinstall kali 2.0 or is this fixable?

Answer (score 7):

(from: https://www.pckr.co.uk/arch-grub-mkconfig-lvmetad-failures-inside-chroot-install/ )

try first to disable lvmetad from `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` and set `use_lvmetad = 0`

I had a similar problem on my Arch Linux VM, and following the commands in that blogpost I linked above helped me to get rid of that error.

I hope It helps, lemme know!

Answer (score 0):

the lvmetad thing (while annoying) isn't the problem.  The main issue there is Kali is hanging w/ a black screen.

You see in the final message that sda5 is clean.  So, booting was proceeding.

PROBABLY (this is what happened to me, anyway) systemd tried to start X but nothing happened.

When this happened to me it was because Kali's automatic approach of software updating broke when I switched to rolling.

To get past the black screen I had to go in as root on tty2 and gently prod dpkg and apt into working again and updating everything.

One reboot after that Kali eventually came up w/ the initial Xwindow  "Username:" dialog.

Here's hoping you have a similarly successful experience getting past this.